# cache implementation on DAO with custom refresh and evictions java

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

In my application, I have a scenario where I have to refresh cache each 24hrs.
I'm expecting database downtime so I need to implement a use case to refresh cache after 24hrs only if the database is up running.

I'm using **spring-ehache** and I did implement simple cache to refresh for each 24 hrs, but unable to get my head around to make the retention possible on database downtime .

Comment: I need throw exception only on first request if database is down on cache load. My fundamental task is to get data from or not to evict cache if the database is down after 24 hrs interval.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you could split the scheduling and cache eviction into two modules and only clear your cache if certain condition (in this case, database's healthcheck returns `true`) is met:

**SomeCachedService.java**:

```
class SomeCachedService {
  @Autowired
  private YourDao dao;

  @Cacheable("your-cache")
  public YourData getData() {
    return dao.queryForData();
  }

  @CacheEvict("your-cache")
  public void evictCache() {
    // no body needed
  }
}
```

**CacheMonitor.java**

```
class CacheMonitor {
  @Autowired
  private SomeCachedService service;

  @Autowired
  private YourDao dao;

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
  public conditionallyClearCache() {
    if (dao.isDatabaseUp()) {
      service.evictCache();
    }  
  }
}
```

[Ehcache also allows you to create a custom eviction algorithm](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/cache-eviction-algorithms#plugging-in-your-own-eviction-algorithm) but the documentation doesn't seem too helpful in this case.

Comment: What about replacing the data in the cache, only if it was successfully fetched?

Comment: The conceptual problem is: Scheduler triggers, database is up, cache is evicted. 5 minutes later the database goes down. Now, the data is accessed again for the first time after the eviction: Fails, since database is down.

Comment: Thank you kryger  !! this approach worked with a small tweak by calling cached method after eviction to make sure the data is cached and available